# What is the meaning of "put your ass in reverse"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, lyrics

I couldn't get the meaning of "put your ass in reverse". I've heard this in Pitbull's song: [Back up](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/pitbull/backup.html). Please clarify.

Comment: Next time, you may wanna try [genius.com](http://genius.com) . This website has mostly lyrics of every song and line to line meaning also.

Comment: @user3461086 Wow! that's great. Thanks a ton for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Trevor Clarke says, it's a rude way of saying, "Back up" or "leave."

It is probably derived from the also-rude saying, "Get your ass in gear" -- comparing someone's buttocks (and leg muscles) to a car that needs to be put into "drive" instead of "neutral" -- i.e., "Get moving! Quickly!"

Answer (score 1):

This means that you most likely walked in on a situation or room, and they are rudely telling you to leave.

Answer (score 0):

Trevor Clarke is probably right about this one, but it's just possible that Pit Bull is asking someone to [twerk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twerking).